How to change the Python LSTM model code to predict Annual wise instead of month wise (Data set contained annual data ) but model gives monthly
This is my first approach to LSTM. I m trying to predict a annual time series. I m following this Github example. But code is giving monthly predictions instead of annual predictions. appreciate your support to identify the changes to the code.
MY data set cointained annual data 
,
I want to change the python code to predict next year value instead of next month value
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

# Normalize the data
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(df_final)

# Define sequence length and features
sequence_length = 1  # Number of time steps in each sequence
num_features = len(df_final.columns)  # Assuming 12 features

# Create sequences and corresponding labels
sequences = []
labels = []
for i in range(len(scaled_data) - sequence_length):
    seq = scaled_data[i:i+sequence_length, :]  # Use all features with [:, :]
   # label = scaled_data[i+sequence_length, 11]  # 'Indnpa' column index
    label = scaled_data[i+sequence_length, 11]  # 'Indnpa' column index
    sequences.append(seq)
    labels.append(label)

# Convert to numpy arrays
sequences = np.array(sequences)
labels = np.array(labels)

# Split into train and test sets
train_size = int(0.8 * len(sequences))
train_x, test_x = sequences[:train_size], sequences[train_size:]
train_y, test_y = labels[:train_size], labels[train_size:]

print("Train X shape:", train_x.shape)
print("Train Y shape:", train_y.shape)
print("Test X shape:", test_x.shape)
print("Test Y shape:", test_y.shape)


Next Code
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint

# Create the LSTM model
model = Sequential()

# Add LSTM layers with dropout
model.add(LSTM(units=128, input_shape=(train_x.shape[1], train_x.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(units=64, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(units=32, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Add a dense output layer
model.add(Dense(units=1))

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

Next Code
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5, restore_best_weights=True)
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('/content/drive/MyDrive/dl/weather_prediction/best_model_weights.h5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)

# Train the model
history = model.fit(
    train_x, train_y,
    epochs=100,
    batch_size=64,
    validation_split=0.2,  # Use part of the training data as validation
    callbacks=[early_stopping, model_checkpoint]
)

Last Code
# Reshape predicted_temp to match the shape of df_final.index
predicted_temp = predicted_temp.reshape(-1, 1)

# Plot the data
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(df_final.index[-2:], true_temp[-2:], label='Actual')
plt.plot(df_final.index[-2:], predicted_temp[-2:], label='Predicted')
plt.title('Industry NPA Prediction vs Actual')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('NPA Ratio')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

enter image description here

The model is predicting annual values, but it appears as monthly values, due to how matplotlib is plotting them. You are plotting the last two values when you use.index[-2:]. The values you are plotting are at 2023-01-01 and 2024-01-01, and matplotlib simply draws a straight line between them.
I think it will become clearer if you plot more values, I marked the values in your plot below:

